# Hide iframe vertical scrollbar and show the whole content

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe and the contents of it go beyond the height of the iframe. I have set the CSS on the iframe to have a height of 100vh, however it crops the content off. I would like to show the **whole content** and **not** show any scrollbar in that iframe.

What is the best way to achieve this?

**HTML**

```
 <iframe id="testIframe" width="100%" scrolling="no" style="display:block;"></iframe>
```

**CSS**

```
iframe {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

**Update:**
I don't want to adjust the scrollbar, I would like to remove them by showing all the content. Imagine it this way, I have an iframe window(non-scrollable) on a page (scrollable).

Comment: But wouldn't that add a vertical scrollbar?

Comment: Add your code in fiddle so that we could view both your css and iframe  codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to resolve this issue myself using this approach with jQuery.

```
$('testIframe').on('load', function(){
      resizeIframe(this);
    });
...
function resizeIframe(obj) {    
  // Initially just set the height to 100% till the inner page loads and once the page inside the iframe is loaded
  // then set the iframe height to match that page height so that it looks seamless to the user
  obj.style.height = "100vH";

  setTimeout(function(){
    obj.style.display = "block";
    obj.style.height = $(obj.contentWindow.document.body).height() + "px";
  }, 1500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust scrollbars of an iframe or any element with following css code:

`iframe{ width:500px; height: 500px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll }`

Comment: I don't want to adjust the scrollbar, I would like to remove them by showing all the content. Imagine it this way, I have an iframe window(non-scrollable) on a page (scrollable).

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the **aspect ratio** of the content from the iframe.
For example in a youtube video it is **16:9**

```
iframe {
    // Aspect ratio 16:9 
    // width:height
    width: 177.77vH;// (100vH / 9) * 16
    height: 100vH;

}
```

Comment: Yes this is fine however I still cannot get rid of the scrollbar and show all content regardless of how long the content is.

Comment: If the aspect ratio is correct, one could see the whole content. `overflow: hidden` should remove the scrollbar.

Comment: Can you share a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ , so that we can better understand, what the problem is.